# Cannot find type definition file for 'jest', even though jest is installed

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, tsconfig, nx-monorepo

### ACTUAL SOLUTION:

If you run into the same issue and (like me) are not satisfied with  'quick & dirty' solutions like those in the answer/comments, you should recreate the repo. It's more work, to have less issues down the road. In my case, the repo was broken by bad migration/s. These things happen sometimes and I've heard some teams re-repo their projects every few months or so.

### Question:

I have a nx repository, inside I have a NextJs app, and its tsconfig.json has this error:

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'jest' specified in compilerOptions
```

The problem used to be just a warning as far as I remember, but after migrating nx repository from 16.3.2, to 16.5.2, this now causes a build error.

I have these installed as devDeps:

```
"@nx/jest": "16.5.2",
"@types/jest": "^29.4.4",
"babel-jest": "29.4.3",
"jest": "29.4.3",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "29.4.3",
"ts-jest": "29.1.0",
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types/next-auth.d.ts",
    ],
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./apps/<app>/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "next-env.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jest.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried:

- deleting node_modules and .next folder, reinstalling modules after closing VSCode and killing all hidden processes that might still be running
- 2 hours of googling

Any ideas what's wrong and how do try and fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the full `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I found out another problem where my DNS would break for 1-3 minutes upon starting the app and visiting index page. I narrowed it down to the Image component from next/image. Really weird stuff... Doesn't happen in a fresh nx+nextjs setup, so I'm just re-creating the repo and moving stuff into the fresh one. Jest issue is gone there as well. :) migrations </3

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. adding `"node"` in the `types` under `compilerOptions` in tsconfig worked for me.   
`types: ["jest", "node"]`

Comment: @kroflic Instead of updating your question, please remove the answer text. Create a new answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Some packages may not include their own type definitions. This error occurs because:

You are using typescript and the compiler cannot find a type definition file inside the package folder in `node_modules` or any of your specified [type roots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots).

---

Jest has type definitions provided by [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). You can install them by running on of the following commands:

##### Using Yarn

```bash
yarn -D add @types/jest
```

##### Using NPM

```bash
npm install @types/jest --save-dev
```

As you can see both of the above commands save this dependency as a development dependency, meaning that the code will not be included in your production bundle. This is optimal for typescript types since your code will be compiled to JS anyway.

##### What if you can't find types for the package?

If you should encounter packages that do not include their own type definitions and no definition was created for it inside the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository, you can always define your own types for the package inside a `.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare module "my-module" {
  // ... type the contents of the package, like functions etc.
}
```

If you create custom type definitions for a package that is not yet typed, consider [contributing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute) to the DefinitelyTyped repository so others can benefit from your types too.

Comment: I have them installed and I've tried reinstalling, I have stated that in the description. :)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't quite catch that. Try `rm -rf node_modules .next`, closing your IDE completely by killing the process and running `yarn install` again.

Comment: Did that before, except checking for hidden vscode processes that might be still running. There actually was one left running even after I closed the app.

Killed it, npm installed everything again. Issue remains. :/

Comment: Are you using ESlint? If so, have you tried restarting the ESlint server?

Comment: As quick and dirty fix you could create a custom type definition and export the contents of `@types/jest` inside the declared module.

Comment: The project is using ESlint, yes, but i think this is all managed by either nextjs or nx monorepo, i never had to manually set that up. Doesn't it restart on VSCode restart or something?

Comment: I mean for a quick and dirty fix i can just remove both 'node' and 'jest' from "types" option in tsconfig.json and VSCode stops showing problems for this file and the app builds. But as these are some default configurations and they suddenly broke, i wonder why and if something else might break. Also i dont like dirty fixes, they tend to bite me in the ass later down the road, so i'm looking for the actual cause of this.

Comment: Also big thanks for trying to help on this, it's a very weird issue with little to go on.